# Stop Sharepoint users editing shared versions of a site?

Tags: permissions, sharepoint

On Windows Sharepoint 3, users who have Collaboration permissions on a site can edit the shared view, so they can change how the site looks for others, adding and removing parts of it. Looking online, the only "fix" I've seen for this is using CSS to hide the Site Settings menu, which isn't really a solution. Can anyone give any pointers? The only permission level below the one they have is read only, which is useless for this site.

The permissions are on the top level of the site, and are being inherited down.

Thanks,

~Dentrasi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. The Sharepoint group `CompanyWebMembers` group had design permissions, and the users were part of the AD group `Windows SBS Sharepoint_Members` group - which made them `CompanyWebMembers`, so they had design permissions...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by *Collaboration permissions* - do you mean they're assigned to the *Contribute* permission level?
If yes, such users should not see the *Site Actions* menu at all.

Is it possible that the default *Contribute* permission level has been modified? Go to `http://[site-collection-url]/_layouts/editrole.aspx?role=Contribute`, check what permissions are included in this level and compare it with [this table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx#BM2).

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back - yes, they have Contribute permissions,and the permissions match those at the link you gave.

Comment: @Dentrasi Then I don't know how to explain it - on my machine users with the *Contribute* permission level don't see the *Site Actions* menu. Can you create a new, empty site collection and check it there?